# jsystem on fail skip to the next test

Tags: java, junit, automated-tests

i have a project in Jsystem, it looks like that :

```
TC1
     test step 1
     test step 2
     test step 3
TC2
     test step 1
     test step 2
     test step 3
```

what im trying to do is if i got an exception on one of the steps, it will stop the current test, and continue to the next one. for example if step 1 in TC1 throws exception, it will automatically jump to TC2 .

any suggestions ?

Comment: can you post the exception?

Comment: there is no specific exception , just want to know if what i want to achieve is possible in Jsystem at all

Answer (score 0):

Probably too late for you, but in case someone else will also need this...

Go to Tools > Jsystem Properties > runnner > scenario.as.test.fail.terminate
and change to true.

Right-click each scenario you like and choose Mark Scenario As Test from the context menu.

Now it should (from my experience it is not exactly stable) stop on fail and skip to the next scenario.

Hope I helped,